# Mysql Querying A Subset of Data

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I have 2 queries, the first query is to list all customer who made purchases from the very beginning of time:

```
SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, c.email, COUNT(o.id_customer) AS 'total'
FROM ps_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN ps_order_state_lang AS osl ON o.current_state = osl.id_order_state
LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE o.current_state IN(2,4,5)
AND osl.id_lang = 2
AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-09-30'
GROUP BY o.id_customer
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

While the second query is to list all customer who made a purchase on a specific period of time:

```
SELECT c.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, COUNT(c.id_customer) AS total
FROM ps_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
AND o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
GROUP BY c.id_customer
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Based on this, how can i get all customers who only made their first purchase based on the period specified on the second query. How can i do this using these 2 queries ? Thanks.

EDIT #1

My current solution is this:

```
SELECT a.id_customer, a.fullname, a.total AS 'this_month', b.total AS 'all_time'
FROM (
    SELECT c.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, COUNT(c.id_customer) AS total
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
    AND o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
    GROUP BY c.id_customer
    HAVING COUNT(c.id_customer) < 2
    ORDER BY total DESC
) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, c.email, COUNT(o.id_customer) AS 'total'
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN ps_order_state_lang AS osl ON o.current_state = osl.id_order_state
    LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE o.current_state IN(2,4,5)
    AND osl.id_lang = 2
    AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2013-12-31' AND '2015-01-01'
    GROUP BY o.id_customer
    HAVING COUNT(o.id_customer) < 2
    ORDER BY total DESC
) AS b ON b.id_customer = a.id_customer
ORDER BY all_time DESC;
```

is there a better way of doing this ?

EDIT 2:

First query is listing of all customers who made purchases at our store from the beginning of time.

Second query is listing of all customer who only made purchases in a specific month.

Based on this 2 queries, i would like to list all customer who made purchases in a specific month for the first time.

EDIT #3:
Perhaps i wasn't very clear with what i want to achieve, so let me elaborate more.

I have a table named ps_orders, which stores all the transaction record from the very beginning. From ps_orders i particularly interested in the following column:

- id_customer
- id_order
- invoice_date

I want to know how many first time buyers from a given period of time. For example:

I want to know how many customer is a first time buyer between 01 january 2015 and 31 january 2015. The following query lists all orders that is made between that exact date:

```
SELECT c.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, COUNT(c.id_customer) AS total
FROM ps_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
AND o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
GROUP BY c.id_customer
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

How ever the result includes the customer who has made purchases in earlier date (e.g. Cust ID 1234 may have purchased in the previous year). However i am only interested only the first time buyer within that period of time. Please see EDIT #1 to see my current solution (it contains some invalid data, but i think i am getting close to what i want)

Comment: Unable to understand the question "first purchase based on the period specified on the second query"?

Comment: Please see my Edit #2 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT o.id_customer, MIN(o.invoice_date) first_purchase
FROM ps_orders AS o
GROUP BY o.id_customer
HAVING first_purchase BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
```

should work, no? I don't see how the all-time purchases are relevant if all you want is the date when a ustomer made their first purchase.

Since it seems you want the customer name and email as well, use this initial query to generate a join table for yourself

```
SELECT c.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, c.email, firsts.first_purchase
FROM (
    SELECT
        o.id_customer cid,
        MIN(o.invoice_date) first_purchase
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    GROUP BY o.id_customer
    HAVING first_purchase BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
) firsts
LEFT JOIN customer c ON firsts.cid = c.id_customer
# If you prefer you may replace the HAVING above with a WHERE here
# WHERE first_purchase BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
```

Comment: Thanks @Thernys, It is suprisingly a short query. Can you elaborate more with the MIN() here ? I didn't know that it can be used in this way, because as far as i know MIN is used if i want to find the minimum value from a record set.

Comment: MIN is one of the [MySQL aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and yes, it is used to find the minimum value from a set of values (a table column). In your case, you want to find the minimum value of the relevant set of dates (smallest/earliest date found for a customer's purchase).

Comment: @Jeremy I was unsure if your `this_month` and `all_time` totals were desired data or just used as a means to an end. They can of course be worked into this query as well.

Comment: i think i am not getting the desired result from your query. But perhaps i wasn't very clear with my question. Please see edit #3 and i hope this time i can explain my question better. Thanks for your help..!

Comment: the this_month and all_time columns is just for me to make a quick check that a particular customer only purchase once in the given period and all_time should be null since it shows the total number of purchase leading up to their first purchase.

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan I do not believe my understanding of your problem was incorrect, based on your new edit. I am unsure why my query wouldn't work for you. [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e7708/1) demonstrates my understanding of the problem, and the validity of my current solution in that context. Users ID 2 and 3, and no others, are returned since their first-time order is within the specified time.

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle of your own, or at least some example data and a desired result based on that example data would be helpful.